# Map Size not updating on map.updateSize()

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, openlayers

I am Using Open layers to publish a Map. But I can't figure out the way to Make the map size dynamic according to Screen Size. As the map remains same on every screen irrespective of the screen size. I also tried map.updatesize(). But that is not working too.
My Code is

```
        layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Basemap',
        baseLayer: true,
        visible: true,
        
        

        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://mlinfomaps.in/geoserver/wms',
            params: { 'LAYERS': 'MSSDS_WS:MSSDS_BASEMAP', 'TILED': true },
            serverType: 'geoserver',
          
            // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
            transition: 0,
            crossOrigin: "anonymous"
        })
    });


    var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
        // be placed within the map.
        //className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
        //undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
    });


    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        //code: 'EPSG: 4326', // *code says: 5261 ...try to see if this is right
        //extent: [71.6142, 22.3645, 81.8754, 15.1508],
        extent:[7970828.0670139585, 1681517.1260521673, 9127778.927138386, 2541280.8202038296]
    })
    function scaleControl() {
        control = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
            units: 'metric',
            bar: true,
            steps: 4,
            text: true,
            
            minWidth: 100
        });
        return control;
    }

    var sourceMeasure = new ol.source.Vector({
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",

        
    });
    var vectorMeasure = new ol.layer.Vector({
       
        source: sourceMeasure,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#df1c29',
                width: 2
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 6,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#df1c29'
                })
            })
        }),
        title: 'Measure Overlay',
    });

    // The Map
    //var overlay = new ol.Overlay
    //    ({
    //        element: container,
    //        autoPan: true,
    //        autoPanAnimation: {
    //            duration: 250
    //        }
    //    });


    var view = new ol.View
        ({
            center: ol.proj.transform([76.7997, 18.6298], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 7,
            extent: projection.getExtent(),
            //minZoom:7,
            maxZoom: 12

        });

    var map = new ol.Map
        ({
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl, scaleControl()]),
            view: view,   
            //fit: view.fit(),
            //overlays: [overlay],
            layers: [layer]
            
        });
    const extent = projection.getExtent()
    map.getView().fit(extent);
    map.updateSize();


    window.onresize = function()
        {
    setTimeout( function() { map.updateSize();}, 200);
        }

    '''
```

The map on different screen looks like this:
On my screen It looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIYio.png

On my colleague's screen it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c4zk.png

Please Help me get through this.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Instead of the same `1 : 4,138,966` scale on both screens do you wish to fit the same region into whatever screen space is available?  If so you should call `view.fit()` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit with the extent of the region after creating the map.

Comment: Sorry Mike ,but I can't Understand what do you want to say. I made a projection with a valid extent and called view.fit() , but no success!

Comment: Anyone please Help !

Answer (score 0):

hello i have the same problem and I solove it by doing that

ts:

[image]

html :

[image]

Comment: it is recommended to add code rather than image